# activating anaconda python even if it's not on conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual-environment

literally.
in cmd, I want to execute window's python, not conda's
but it always executes conda's
Like this:

```
C:\Users\RHS>python
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  4 2022, 05:22:27) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Warning:
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has
not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment
please see https://conda.io/activation

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

What I want to execute is window's python.
Like this:

```
C:\Users\RHS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39>python
Python 3.9.13 (tags/v3.9.13:6de2ca5, May 17 2022, 16:36:42) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I added PATH of python 3.9 and tried changing position of both.
but always same result

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I just put images because it is not a matter of code.